# search and count specific character in each value of array in swift

Tags: массивы, swift

В приведенном ниже массиве для каждой строки посчитать количество букв "e" и вывести строки в порядке убывания этого значения. Количества букв "e" должно также выводиться для каждой строки. Разницу между большими и маленькими буквами не учитывать.

```
let romeoAndJuliet = [

    "Act 1 Scene 1: Verona, A public place",

    "Act 1 Scene 2: Capulet's mansion",

    "Act 1 Scene 3: A room in Capulet's mansion",

    "Act 1 Scene 4: A street outside Capulet's mansion",

    "Act 1 Scene 5: The Great Hall in Capulet's mansion",

    "Act 2 Scene 1: Outside Capulet's mansion",

    "Act 2 Scene 2: Capulet's orchard",

    "Act 2 Scene 3: Outside Friar Lawrence's cell",

    "Act 2 Scene 4: A street in Verona",

    "Act 2 Scene 5: Capulet's mansion",

    "Act 2 Scene 6: Friar Lawrence's cell"

]

var c : Character = "e"
var sortedText: [(String, Int)] = []

for arrayIndex in romeoAndJuliet {
    var temp = 0
    for char in arrayIndex.characters {
        if char == c {
            temp += 1
        }
    }
    print("\(temp)number of \(arrayIndex)")
}
```

Comment: что пробовали? что не получается?

Answer (score 3):

Могу подсказать как сделать:

1. Считаете сколько "е" в каждом элементе массива
2. Ассоциируете количество "е" с элементом массива. К примеру, массив тюплов: [(количество, индекс)] или [(количество, элемент)], или как Вам удобнее.
3. Сортируете п.2 по убыванию количества элементов.
4. Выводите результат.

Для подсчета "е" в строке, вариант первый однострочный:

```
let eCount = romeoAndJuliet[i].lowercased().components(separatedBy: "e").count-1
```

Вариант второй:

```
let eCount = countFor(pattern: "[(Ee)]", in: str)

func countFor(pattern: String, in text: String) -> Int {
    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])
        return regex.matches(in: text, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, text.count)).count
    } catch {
        print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return 0
    }
}
```